# Different colors below/above bar of boxplot in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

For some reason I want the colors above and below the median bar to have different colors. Is there an easy way to achieve this?

```
library(datasets) 
library(ggplot2)
data(airquality)
airquality$Month <- factor(airquality$Month,
                           labels = c("May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep"))
ggplot(airquality, aes(x = Month, y = Ozone, fill=Month)) +  
  geom_boxplot()
```

I saw something similar for polygen and for another function of boxplot, but I would like to stay with ggplot

[image: Graph for illustration]

Ok thx to the comment I kinda figured out where to go, but I am stuck on the execution. I need to establish the points from the graph coordinates. But this is rather tedious.

> g<-ggplot(airquality, aes(x = Month, y = Ozone, fill=Month)) +
>   geom_boxplot()
>
> coords<-ggplot_build(g)$data        # use ggbuild to get the outline
>   co-ords d<-coords[[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bhml9.png)]                      # this gets the df in a
>   usable form groups<-unique(d$group)             # get the unique
>   "violin" ids names(d)
>
> testdf<-rbind(data.frame(x=d$x,y= c(d$middle,d$upper,d$lower)),
>                 data.frame(x=d$xmin,y= c(d$middle,d$upper,d$lower)),
>                 data.frame(x=d$xmax,y= c(d$middle,d$upper,d$lower)) )
>
> ggplot(testdf)+geom_point(aes(x=x,y=y))

to use geom_polygone i need to have the right order to create my data frame of 5 * 9 coordinates and then I also need a grouping variable below and above the median. Does someone have a neat solution for this? Mine would be very manual

Comment: Do you want to maintain the categorical coloring for the months?

Comment: No, not neccesarily. I would also be happy with dark grey/light grey. I guess, I could then manually adjust it

Comment: You can probably find good information here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22278951/combining-violin-plot-with-box-plot

Comment: Thx this would be rather complicated and i was not able to directly adjust it to geom_boxplot. Maybe there is an easier solution?